# How to bind a specific object to this keyword in global function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function defined and I would like to have `console.log(this)` to return the original array [3,4,5]. However, It returns a window object. I tried to use apply and bind, It didn't work.

Sorry,I am new to Javascript, Thank you in advance!

```
function Filterstuff(arr) {
    var currentArray = arr;
    return (function arrayFilterer(predicate,callback) {
        if(typeof predicate != "function")
            return currentArray;
        currentArray = currentArray.filter(predicate);
        callback.apply(arr,currentArray); // call back apply
        if(typeof callback == "function")
            callback(currentArray); 
        return arrayFilterer;
    });
}



var arrayFilterer = Filterstuff([3,4,5]); 

arrayFilterer(function (elem) {
  return elem !== 4; 
}, function (currentArray) {
  console.log(this); 
  console.log(currentArray);
});
```

Result: round one console.log(this) returns original array , but round 2 it returns window again [image: result]

Comment: Why would `this` ever be the array in that context, and why would you want it to ?

Comment: Also, it's a very bad idea to add enumerable properties to `Array.prototype` like that. If you want to extend `Array.prototype`, use `Object.defineProperty` to define a non-enumerable property.

Comment: Should the log not be in a function to which you need to bind something

Comment: @Rajesh I just updated the code.

Comment: @adeneo I just updated the code. I think it makes more sense now .

Comment: Why are you writing a filter function that passes its result to a callback?

Comment: @Bergi I am not allowed to invoke any javascript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `apply` would work, or the even simpler `call`:

```
function filterStuff(originalArray) {
    return function arrayFilterer(predicate, callback) {
        var resultArray = originalArray.filter(predicate);
        callback.call(originalArray, resultArray);
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering the question. after using the call method. the console.log(this) did return the original array, but it also returns a window object. How would you make sure that it returns the original array only ?

Comment: @Snailwalker Wat? It can't be both. Maybe you were looking at the `this` keyword in a different function?

Comment: I think it's because of the filter loop. it has to loop two times because the length of the array is 3. Basically, the second round console.log(this) returns a window object again. I couldn't find a way to deal with it.

Comment: @Snailwalker Please post the code that's not working. My answer works with the code in the question.

Comment: @Snailwalker Well `callback.apply(arr,currentArray); … callback(currentArray);` is *not* the code from my answer. It even calls `callback` twice now for some reason.